# Problem alert after updating Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, updates

In the last days I get some generic "Problem" window popping out after turning on the PC. This happens after I received the last suggested updates (three days ago?):

[image]

If I click on "Report problem" the system ask me to enter the root password. I'm not sure if this action is safe, so I always gave up...

[image]

Any suggestion to fix this behaviour?

---

LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine to enter the password.

Also, you can have a look if there are dumps under /var/crash. I believe there used to be a bug, as I got this message after every restart of my desktop if I didn't close chrome before reboot. I could remove the warning by deleting the contents of /var/crash.

Comment: Ok. I entered the root password and I've got the details of the alert.
It is an executable: 

executable path = /usr/bin/whoopsie
package = whoopsie 0.2.52.5ubuntu0.5

No idea what this application does... anyway I clicked on "Continue" to send the error report (I don't know where : )